# Should I use a lock to write to class variables (during threading) even if each variable is not accessed/written into by other threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, python-multithreading

I have a class which parses a LOT of strings. There are 6 main variables being written into by 6 threads. Total character count of all strings together will cross 500,000 characters.

Each thread works independently, ie, all of their strings does not collide with or are referenced by other strings. Meaning all threads work exclusive of each other regarding inputs and when outputting, they only write to their variable in the class.

Should I implement a lock mechanism in the class during writing into those variables?

EDIT1: Completed the threading. However, to compare speed of execution, I ran all concurrently too. I found it takes 1.44 seconds when run sequentially and takes 2.33 seconds when threaded. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to ensure that anything using those class attributes doesn't use stale data then use a lock so *they* can't be read till it is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the memory accessed by each thread is independent then you don't need any synchronization. If you plan on accessing these results from a main thread afterwards you need some synchronization at the end, but waiting for the worker threads to finish should be enough.

That's the general answer. Python's threading is limited due to the GIL, so you probably don't need anything at all. You won't see the speedup you expect either.

Comment: Yup. No Speedup at all. In fact time of execution increases by about 0.9 seconds.

Comment: Any thoughts what I should do to speed it up? I expected it to take 0.3-0.4 sec instead of 1.44 sec when split across 6 threads (with somewhat even work load across threads)

Answer (score 2):

if your class level variables to be updated by all the threads you need to use class level lock as follows.

```
class Parser(object):
  sharedLock = threading.Lock()
  var1 = var2 = var3 = var4 = var5 = var6 = 0

  @classmethod
  def update(cls):
    with cls.sharedLock:
      # update your variables.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My class's variables are updated by all threads, but are exclusive. Ie, VarWrite1 will  be only written into by thread1 by reading VarRead1, VarWrite2 will  be only written into by thread2 by reading VarRead2 etc. So should i use locks still?

Comment: as long as they are independent, you no need locks. synchronization(locks) only comes into picture, when two threads access to a shared variable.